# Strange Rails ActiveRecord Behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Can someone please explain why the following queries return diff results?

If I run a simple "last" query I get an object back.

```
    >> j = Job.last
   (1.6ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
   Job Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" ORDER BY "jobs"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   => #<Job id: 12, customer_id: 3, description: nil, shoot_start_date: "2020-11-25 
00:00:00", shoot_end_date: "2020-11-26 00:00:00", submission_deadline: "2020-11-27 
00:00:00", delivery_deadline: "2020-11-28 00:00:00", created_at: "2020-11-25 21:44:22", 
updated_at: "2020-12-14 19:30:06", token: "fd2356c1-996b-4f95-b24a-8c92829af1fe", name: 
"teesting">
```

And with this object I can get children as follows:

```
>> j.job_entries
JobEntry Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "job_entries".* FROM "job_entries" WHERE 
"job_entries"."job_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["job_id", 12], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<JobEntry id: 8, entity_id: 12, 
agency_id: 35, created_at: "2020-12-07 21:27:47", updated_at: "2020-12-07 21:27:47", job_id: 
12, job_role_id: 8>, #<JobEntry id: 9, entity_id: 13, agency_id: 35, created_at: "2020-12-14 
17:35:30", updated_at: "2020-12-14 17:35:30", job_id: 12, job_role_id: 7>]>
```

**HOWEVER**, when I run a method on my object which is the following code:

```
  def self.getJobAndSubmissions(token)
    Job.includes(job_entries: :images_attachments).where(:token => token)
  end
```

I get the very same record with attachments:

```
>> j = Job.getJobAndSubmissions('fd2356c1-996b-4f95-b24a-8c92829af1fe')
Job Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."token" = ? LIMIT ?  [["token", 
"fd2356c1-996b-4f95-b24a-8c92829af1fe"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
JobEntry Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "job_entries".* FROM "job_entries" WHERE 
"job_entries"."job_id" = ?  [["job_id", 12]]
ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM 
"active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND 
"active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" IN (?, 
?)  [["record_type", "JobEntry"], ["name", "images"], ["record_id", 8], ["record_id", 9]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Job id: 12, customer_id: 3, description: nil, 
shoot_start_date: "2020-11-25 00:00:00", shoot_end_date: "2020-11-26 00:00:00", 
submission_deadline: "2020-11-27 00:00:00", delivery_deadline: "2020-11-28 00:00:00", 
created_at: "2020-11-25 21:44:22", updated_at: "2020-12-14 19:30:06", token: "fd2356c1-996b- 
4f95-b24a-8c92829af1fe", name: "teesting">]>
```

But suddenly, child references no longer work.

```
>> j.job_entries
Traceback (most recent call last):
    1: from (irb):4
Job Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."token" = ? LIMIT ?  [["token", 
"fd2356c1-996b-4f95-b24a-8c92829af1fe"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
JobEntry Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "job_entries".* FROM "job_entries" WHERE 
"job_entries"."job_id" = ?  [["job_id", 12]]
ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM 
"active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND 
"active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" IN (?, 
?)  [["record_type", "JobEntry"], ["name", "images"], ["record_id", 8], ["record_id", 9]]

NoMethodError (undefined method `job_entries' for #. 
<Job::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005562db1258c0>)
Did you mean?  entries
```

What the?  Please help me understand why this is happening!

Answer (score 1):

```rb
Job.last
```

will return an ActiveRecord object.

```rb
Job.includes(job_entries: :images_attachments).where(:token => token)
```

returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which means you can't call `job_entries` on it.

You can get an object with this code

```rb
# These do the same thing
Job.find_by_token(token)
Job.find_by(token: token)
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> NoMethodError (undefined method `job_entries' for #. <Job::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00005562db1258c0>)
> ```

Note the error message is not for `Job` but for a `Job::ActiveRecord_Relation`.

[`#last`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last) returns a single Job. [`#where`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) returns a set of Jobs stored in an ActiveRecord::Relation. Job::ActiveRecord_Relation is a relation specific to Job.

You can also see this in the returned value...

> ```
> >> j = Job.getJobAndSubmissions('fd2356c1-996b-4f95-b24a-8c92829af1fe')
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Job id: 12, ...]>
> ```

Comment: Thanks to both comments!  Makes sense.  Onward!